# Invalid Cast Exception DBQuery LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

On this Function I get an Invalid Cast Exception with this as the Detailed error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType8`2[System.Nullable`1[System.TimeSpan],System.String]]' to type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[YourReservation.Models.Reservation]'.

Code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Reservations/getPartyNames")]
public IOrderedQueryable<Reservation>getPartyNames()
{
    var query = (from r in db.Reservations
                 where r.ReservationDate == DateTime.Now
                 select new { Time = r.ReservationTime, FullName = r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName });

    return (IOrderedQueryable<Reservation>)query;
}
```

I don't exactly see what is wrong because I have made this particular cast on a return variable numerous times before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a conversion `Select`.

```
return query.Select(v => new Reservation { v.Time, v.FullName });
```

You cannot convert an anonymous type (`new {}` syntax) to a normal type directly like that.

Also note that this wouldn't be an OrderedQueryable, you would be returning an `IEnumerable<Reservation>`.

Comment: Note it's also possible (assuming the properties are public) to simply add `Reservation` after the `new` (IE: `select new Reserveration { Time = r.Res... }`) and keep the rest the same

Comment: @Rob Does the variables in the select new clause have to be identical to a field in my Reservation class? I get the error Reservation does not contain two constructors.

Comment: @GabeCoach Yes - they would have to match. Assuming you have a property `Time` and `Fullname`, it should work. I'm not too sure about that error though, as you'd be using the default constructor. Can we see the Reservation class?

Comment: @Rob: He probably doesn't have a constructor like I assumed, updated to use initialization syntax.

Answer (score 1):

In LINQ, if no type is specified after new keyword in select part then the result type is anonymous and your method has return type:

```
IOrderedQueryable<Reservation>
```

Anonymous types are class types that derive directly from object, and that cannot be cast to any type except object.(Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb397696.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Thus, you just have to mention the type i.e. Reservation in select part of linq as mentioned below

```
 var query = (from r in db.Reservations
             where r.ReservationDate == DateTime.Now
             select new Reservation { Time = r.ReservationTime, FullName = r.FirstName + " " + r.LastName });
```